# Deriving posterior for weights in bayesian linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, bayesian, linear-model, posterior

Given is a linear model $y_i=x_i^T+e_i$ where $e_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. The precision is defined as $\tau = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$. I am asked to derive the posterior $\pi(\beta|x,\tau)$.

Would I compute the posterior by doing the following:
$\pi(\beta|x,\tau) \propto p(x, \tau | \beta) p(\beta)$
or
$\pi(\beta|x,\tau) \propto p(x,|\tau, \beta) p(\tau |\beta) p(\beta)$?

I would assume the above relations to be equivalent;
How do the mathematical expressions of the pdfs of $p(x, \tau | \beta)$ and $p(x,|\tau, \beta$) differ?

Comment: Your question is missing the prior distribution on $\beta$ and $\sigma$. The first equation is furthermore missing a $\beta$.

Comment: I think the previous question and my answer cover your question.